# C# CreateDirectory behaving strange - Not creating directory

Tags: c#, file-io, directory

I am deleting a directory if it exists, and re-creating that directory.

My code is like this:

```
                if (Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                {
                    Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);
                    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
                }
                else
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
                }
```

The problem I am facing is: if the directory already contains files AND that directory is currently open in one of the Windows explorer windows (even though no file is open in any application), then:

1. Directory.Delete deletes the directory, and the Explorer window automatically navigates to the parent folder.
2. CreateDirectory does not throw any error, but the DirectoryInfo returned by it contains Exists as false.

Due to this, later in my program when I am trying to create files in that directory, I get the error: "Could not find a part of the path"

Why is this behaviour and what is the solution?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:
Sometimes DirectoryInfo.Exists returns true, but the directory does not actually exist in Explorer!

Comment: In my test Directory.Exist and DirectoryInfo.Exist return true after Delete and re creation.

Comment: Check my EDIT above. Can you verify whether the Directory actually got created, even though Exists = true? Did you ensure that the directory has files, and the directory is open in one of the explorer windows?

Comment: I put Thread.Sleep(100) before, it works fine.

Comment: Any chance that this folder has read-only files?

Comment: No, the folder has read-write files and no permission issue. @vivek nuna, Surprisingly, Thread.Sleep(100) works even for me! But why is this required?

Comment: Lots of programs like to open a handle on a directory.  Most commonly because such a program uses the equivalent of FileSystemWatcher (like Explorer does).  Or because the directory is the program's Environment.CurrentDirectory.  That handle is opened with the equivalent of FileShare.Delete.  In other words, deleting works just fine but it won't actually disappear until all handles are closed.  The latter clause is the problem, CreateDirectory() cannot succeed until that happened.  How long that takes is completely unpredictable.  You could rename the dir or move it to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem operations are not synchronous.

The [RemoveDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365488%28VS.85%29.aspx) function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.
As you see, it will not really delete directory until all handles to it are closed, but `Directory.DeleteDirectory` will complete fine. In your case that is also most likely such concurrency problem - directory is not really created while you executing `Directory.Exists`. So you can use RemoveDirectory function also in your case.

Or You can check it periodically using code if you want otherwise use `Thread.Sleep()`.

```
            if (Directory.Exists(destFolder))
            {
                Directory.Delete(destFolder, true);     
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
            }
```

One more solution:

```
if (Directory.Exists(destFolder))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(destFolder);

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                file.Delete();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                dir.Delete(true);

            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);

        }
```

Comment: Ok. I will accept this unless I get any other alternate solution without using Thread.Sleep

Comment: @viveknuna, Good two method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a solution akin to vivek nuna's that doesn't use Thread.Sleep:

You could also use a FileSystemWatcher to watch for the deletion of the directory.  This should in the normal case be faster than a Thread.Sleep.

However, if you take this route also set a timer and check if the directory vanished without you being told.  FileSystemWatcher fails silently when the system hosting the drive does not support the notifications.